# Remove Unwanted 0's from numeric element - R

Tags: r, significant-digits

New R-bie,

I am trying to clean 3 columns of data from my dataframe `df`. The columns consist of numeric elements that range in their value from 0.19, 687.00, 49405, 107.440, 13764.000, 1.740. I will create `df` below for the purpose of this example. The goal is going to be to implement this line of code into a mutate function from dplyr so clean a column of data from `data.frame`.

Example:

```
 df <- c(1.560, 1.790, 3456.000, 1.0700, 0.16000, 1.347, 4.200)
```

I have been trying to remove the 0's at the end of the elements so that they all look like this

```
df <- c(1.56, 1.79, 3456, 1.07, 0.16, 1.347, 4.20)
```

I can partially achieve my desired results by running the line of code below:

```
signif(df[1], 5) 
signif(df[2], 5) 
signif(df[3], 5) 
signif(df[4], 5) 
signif(df[5], 5)
signif(df[6], 5) 
signif(df[7], 5)
```

with the df[7] element `4.200` returning `4.2`

Although I have to do this one by one otherwise if I do:  `signif(df[1:6], 5)`, i get this vector returned `1.560    1.790 3456.000    1.070    0.160    1.347    4.200`

2. I have also tried using regex to extract the patterns of 0's at the end of the object, but any quantifiers or expression I use seems to remove all the trailing zeros.
   I was thinking of removing the last digit if it were a 0, to leave numbers like `1.347` as they were, but clean the rest of the column to then remove an exact match of `".00"` to get a whole integer leaving `3456` and '4.20'.
   When using `"(\\.000)$"` to match and remove 0's from (eg. `4128.000, 13764.000`), other elements also have their 0's removed (eg. `4.2`, `0.9`) instead of leaving `4.200` and `0.900`, from which I'd like to extract `4.20` and `0.90`.
   Using `"(0)$"` doesn't work either, and I have tried a plethora of regex variations to achieve this...any ehlp would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that the trailing "000"'s disappear with `sub` or `gsub` using that pattern, but not because of the pattern matching any characters. Rather it's entirely because of the initial conversion to "character" class:

```
>  df <- c(1.560, 1.790, 3456.000, 1.0700, 0.16000, 1.347, 4.200)
> 
> sub("\\.000","",df)
[1] "1.56"  "1.79"  "3456"  "1.07"  "0.16"  "1.347" "4.2"  
> as.character(df)  #no `sub(` at all
[1] "1.56"  "1.79"  "3456"  "1.07"  "0.16"  "1.347" "4.2"
```

And if you wanted 2 digits to the right of the decimal point you could do:

```
format(as.vector(df), digits=2)
[1] "   1.56" "   1.79" "3456.00" "   1.07" "   0.16" "   1.35" "   4.20"
```

And to get rid of the quotes use `print`(although they remain character value so you cannot use arithmetic operators on that result.:

```
print(format(as.vector(df), digits=2) , quote=FALSE)
[1]    1.56    1.79 3456.00    1.07    0.16    1.35    4.20
```